# Get all selected values from uniqueID CheckBoxList in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have create a list of CheckBoxList like that:

```
DDL.ID = "DDL_" & SelectedCategory & "_" & SubAssy & "_" & ProductType
                        RBL.ID = "RBL_" & SelectedCategory & "_" & SubAssy & "_" & ProductType
                        CBL.ID = "CBL_" & SelectedCategory & "_" & SubAssy & "_" & ProductType
```

ID from DDL.ID generate like that: CBL_Seatbel_General_General

How get all selected values by this unique ID?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solutin for another people:

```
            Dim GeneralCBL As CheckBoxList = gvr.FindControl("CBL_Seatbelt_General_General")
            Dim Count0 As Integer = GeneralCBL.Items.Count

            For i = 0 To Count0 - 1
                If GeneralCBL.Items(i).Selected = True Then

                Else

                End If
            Next
```